# Why are solutions to the Loewner equation analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the Loewner differential equation

$$\frac{\partial g_t(z)}{\partial t} = \frac{2}{g_t(z) - \sqrt{\kappa} B_t}$$

where $B_t$ is a 1-dimensional standard Brownian motion starting at the origin. The solutions $g_t(z)$ should give a family of conformal maps wherever they are defined. I don't see why a solution $g_t(z)$ has to be analytic in $z$. I'm guessing that something like Cauchy-Kowalevski has to be used somehow, but to apply such theorems, we require the function $2/(g - \sqrt{\kappa} B_t)$ to be analytic, which it is not.

Comment: Where is the $=$ sign?

Comment: The reason you say $2/(g - \sqrt{\kappa} B_t)$ is not analytic is that it is not with respect to $t$ since $B$ is not, right?

Answer (score 2):

> The fact that $g_t(z)$ is analytic in $z$ is clear, since the right-hand side is analytic in $g_t(z)$.

(Rohde and Schramm, [Basic properties of SLE](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0106036)).

[Goluzin's book](http://books.google.com/books/about/Geometric_Theory_of_Functions_of_a_Compl.html?id=DKcqhBr1SooC) presents a self-contained treatment of the deterministic (radial) Loewner equation with piecewise continuous driving term $k(s)$. He actually works with the inverse map and proves its analyticity, along with existence and uniqueness, by following the proof of the Picard existence theorem. I think for the chordal process this would work too: let $g_{0}(z,t)=z$, and for $n\ge 1$
$$g_{n}(z,t) = z+\int_0^t \frac{2}{g_{n-1}(z,s)-k(s)}\,ds$$  Then each $g_n(\cdot, t)$ is holomorphic in $z$ on its domain, and $g_n(\cdot, t)\to g(\cdot, t)$ uniformly on compact subsets of the domain of $g(\cdot,t)$.

Comment: "The fact that $g_t(z)$ is analytic in $z$ is clear, since the right-hand side is analytic in $g_t(z)$." I don't understand this argument (sorry, I know next to nothing about PDEs). What theorem is this invoking?